# Image feature extraction in Hadoop

Tags: image-processing, hadoop2

I am doing a research on parallel image feature extraction on large scale image datasets. I just got the idea. but i don't know how to start this research. Is it possible in hadoop?

Comment: yes we can do this with hadoop but for this you need to provide some background of what features you want to extract and how you currently doing without hadoop

Comment: We usually use matlab for feature extraction. But considering large scale dataset it is time consuming. HOG (histogram of oriented gradients) and LBP (local binary pattern) are the features which I am going to extract.